# How to delete a field in a collection with firebase-admin?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a collection like this into firebase realtime database:

[image]

I need to delete the first element (the one that finishes with *Wt6J*) from server side using `firebase-admin`.

I have this simple code:

```
const deleteNotification = () => {
  const key1 = 'FhN6Ntw8gyPLwJYVzcHy0E8Wq5z2';
  const key2 = '-MzGhZ2psGLivIfTWt6J';
  const notsRef = db.ref(`notifications/${key1}/${key2}`);
  notsRef.remove();
};
```

This doesn't work. What method should I use to delete a specific field? How do you think I can do it?

Comment: This code looks fine to me at first glance. But `remove()` is an asynchronous operation, so are you sure the process doesn't exit before the delete/write operation has been completed?

Comment: Have you tried adding `then` and `catch` to the `remove()` method call and debugging it that way?

Comment: Thank you guys the problem was `key2` that is passed dynamically but wasn't what I thought in my code. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

I would think to use await in a try catch block.
Await starts another thread which returns once it has completed.
As people said above - your cloud function is likely being killed before the remove actually happens.

```
const deleteNotification = async () => {
  try{
    const key1 = 'FhN6Ntw8gyPLwJYVzcHy0E8Wq5z2';
    const key2 = '-MzGhZ2psGLivIfTWt6J';
    const notsRef = db.ref(`notifications/${key1}/${key2}`);
    await notsRef.remove();
  } catch( err ) {
    console.log( 'failed to remove record.' );
    console.log( err );
  }
  console.log( 'removed record successfully.' );
};
```